# Glanz in Keuns “Das kunstseidene Mädchen”

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature

The word *Glanz* is adopted by Irmgard Keun in the work *[Das kunstseidene Mädchen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_kunstseidene_M%C3%A4dchen)* and it is a keyword belonging to the trend “Neue Sachlichkeit”. 
*Glanz* is meant to describe a synesthetic experience in the metropolis, that shines of this Glanz. But it is a dazzling brightness, it doesn’t just illuminate.

What I did not get, is the meaning that brings this word in the context of Doris’ story. In the so criticized metropolis, she creates his freedom and directs her glance to the city like it was a way of learning. The original fact is that she uses her eyes as a camera to catch everything that happens to make, in the end, this story, that is a kind of film; so she uses the “dehumanising mass media” as a new way of doing literature. And the text talks about her, taken by an inebriating vision.

Would it be possible that *Glanz* has a correlation with the English word *glance* in this case?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: It is never used even remotely in that sense. However, we would need the full excerpt to answer that question.

Comment: The German _Glanz_ is English _gloss_. The English word _Glace_ is a false friend and means _Blick_.

Comment: I didn't write Glace, but Glance

Comment: I have an spelling mistake in my comment: The English word _Gla**n**ce_ is a false friend and means _Blick_.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the "gloss" is actually referring to the glossy "kunstseiden" textile in the title, and thus referring to the cheap imitation of something valuable - silk.